# sp_executesql: как передать в пареметре NULL-значени для DATETIME?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

есть формирование команды в C#:

```
string commExec=@"
EXEC dbo.test
    @id
    , @dat_end
";
object[] commParam = new object[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@id", vm.Item.id),
    new SqlParameter("@dat_end", vm.Item.dat_end??(DateTime?) null)
};
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commExec, commParam);
```

которая шлёт на сервер вот это:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
EXEC dbo.test
    @id
    , @dat_end
',N'@id int, @dat_end datetime'
,74, @dat_end=default
```

и при vm.Item.dat_end=null получаю ошибку сервера: 
Параметризованный запрос "(@id int, @dat_end datetime)

> EXEC dbo.test
>      @id
>     , @dat_en" ожидает параметр "@dat_end", который не был указан.

Как послать null?

Comment: DBNull.Value надо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373595/call-stored-procedure-with-a-null-parameter-value-with-entityframework

Comment: Огромное спасибо, товарищи!! Помог пример с конвертированием от Yaant'a)